# When will DSCOVR appear too close to the Sun for reliable downlinking?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, lagrangian-points, halo-orbit, dscovr, lissajous-orbit

DSCOVR is in a Lissajous orbit about the Sun-Earth L2 point. That the orbit is called Lissajous rather than halo means that it's periods of horizontal libration and vertical libration are not equal. If they were equal it would make a roughly closed loop over and over again, but since they are different it zigzags like an oscilloscope with its horizontal and vertical deflection connected to two unrelated oscillators.

I think the horizontal and vertical motion were phased such that the orbit was a diagonal ellipse, and over time it opened up into a rough circle, but this will continue until the oscillations will approach 0 or 180 degrees in phase, and the diagonal ellipse will collapse into roughly a diagonal line, passing in front of the Sun.

**Question:** When will DSCOVR appear too close to the Sun for reliable downlinking? Can they do anything about this; is there some kind of trajectory correction maneuver possible?

Comment: DSN typically says they can't do anything within ~2.5 degrees, I think, of the disk center but we've found they can often initiate and maintain telemetry lock down to ~1.8 degrees.  Not sure if that helps because it's also spacecraft dependent (i.e., depends on transponder frequency and power).